# RESTful PUT and hacking the URI

Tags: security, rest, put

I'm learning about RESTful interfaces.  To update a server resource, say for a Contact with (id = 1) I'd PUT it:

```
PUT /contact/1
```

Now suppose the current user belongs to Organization 1, which owns Contact 1.  There is also Organization 2, with Contact 2.  The current user doesn't belong to Org 2 and has no rights to it.  If the user hacks the web page (using Firebug for Mozilla or the "F12 debugger" for MSIE) and changes the web page request to point at /contact/2, the browser will merrily submit the request.

My server must protect against such cross-organization attacks.  In my current web site design, once the user logs in I store a data object in the session (I'm using Tomcat/Java).  That object stores which organization the user belongs to.  Safety checking code compares the organization for the passed-back PUT request against the organization the user belongs to and sees if the passed-back data belongs to the user's organization.  On detection of a hack (the user for org 1 is trying to modify contact 2, belonging to org 2) an error is returned to the browser.

I understand that REST is supposed to be stateless, but I'm currently using some state.  Yet, if I pass the user information into the web page I think that this, too, can be hacked through Firebug, et.al.

**How to achieve this safety without invoking server state?**

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: You need include authentication with every request, either as a session cookie or an OAuth-style signature.

Comment: @SLaks - I happen to agree - care to expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

RESTful services are usually stateless.
This means that every request has to be authenticated with an apikey or something else.

So the request will be `/path?apikey=MYKEY` and the server will handle the rights of that apikey.

By the way I've also tried stateful rest services, and the server is able to understand the session by a cookie initialized during the login (but that's not really RESTful).

If you want to try them with curl do something like:

```
curl -c cookie.txt -d "user=username&password=pass" "my.login.path"
curl -b cookie.txt "do.something"
```

Comment: Aaaah, but can you write a cookie that can't be hacked, that says "I'm with org 1"?  The session object has the virtue of being user untouchable.  As far as 'authenticate with each request', I hope that this doesn't mean username/password stored in the web page each time.  For that matter, if the authenticate version is storing in the web page a hash of some sort (apikey), doesn't that require that the server stores the match to that key for that user?  And isn't that session state, too?

Comment: The only thing that can save you form an "hacked" cookie is https. SSL is the only method to avoid MIM attacks. The authentication for each service means that everytime the user do something, the server will take the apikey and see if the user with that apikey can do that thing. This is stateless because the server is not remembering any previous actions from that user.

Comment: Tell me if I've got a clue here.  I have a username/password in a user DB (possibly only a password hash) and a somehow-generated apikey.  At login I find the user record thru the username/password combo and get the apikey, passing it back to the browser in a cookie.  Future server requests look for the apikey to find that user record again, which tells me the allowed Org access for that user.  If all this is true, is there also a timeout mechanism, where the user needs to login again after xx minutes inactivity?  After all, I'm not using Tomcat's session management.